# Jmeter log to display details per thread group in html log

Tags: jmeter

I have a testplan and the testplan has 2 thread groups. Both the thread groups call almost same http requests. I run the test from the command prompt and generate a html report. But in the report, the html calls are mixed up. Is there a way for me to see the calls per each thread group?

Answer (score 0):

Use [__threadGroupName() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) as prefix/postfix for your [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) labels like:

```
${__threadGroupName} - HTTP Request 1
```

This way you will get the relevant Thread Group name added to your sampler label:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)